# React update list after change via API

Tags: reactjs, api

I've created a very simple list as an exercise and now I'm trying to perform some CRUD operations over it.
Problem is that when I delete an item, it appears like the container is fetching the data BEFORE actually deleting the item.
I'm using a Rails API backed, and from the console I can clearly see that the two fetch calls are overlapping; first the items are loaded and then the item is deleted.
I tried wrapping the last line of the `deleteItem` function from this:

```
; this.fetchItems();
```

to this:

```
.then(this.fetchItems());
```

but still the problem occurs, and I have no clue why.

Code simplified for clarity:

**Items.jsx (collection container)**

```
import Item from './Item'

class Items extends Component {
  state = { items: [] }

  fetchItems = () => {
    fetch('/api/v1/items')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          items: responseJson
        });
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchItems();
  }

  deleteItem = (id) => {
    fetch('/api/v1/items/' + id, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
    })
    .then(this.fetchItems());
  }

  render() {
    var items = this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
      return <Item
                key={item.id} 
                itemName={item.name} 
                itemId={item.id} 
                onDelete={this.deleteItem} />
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Items;
```

**Item.jsx (actual item)**

```
class Item extends Component {
  state = { id: this.props.itemId, name: this.props.itemName }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.state.id)}>
        {this.state.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track by adding the then, however I think that is where the immediate re load is happening.

Try adding a function call within the then as below

```
.then(() => this.fetchItems());
```

Sorry for the many "I thinks" but am not near a computer at the moment I can test on.

Comment: Not sorry, since it worked right away; could you explain a little bit in depth? Why was the function called immediately if it was inside the then block? Sorry but I'm really noob about promises and so on

Comment: Then, needs you to pass it a function which it will call when the promise resolves.  By passing a function (callback) then this is not executed until the promise resolves.

Comment: Sorry hadn't finished.  When you write this.fetchItems() then you are essentially executing this code and then passing it to then.   By passing a function you prevent the execution until the promise calls it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably study more about those fancy arrow functions

Comment: Its doesn't have to be an arrow, I prefer them but you could do

Comment: .then(function() {})